# Coda 2.2 Plugins don't stay installed

Tags: plugins, coda

I am having a small problem with plugins not staying installed with Coda 2.2 for Mac on OSX 10.6. Every time I close Coda and open it back up and then click on plugins half of them are gone even though the are in the plugins folder for the application. I have to close Coda and uninstall and reinstall the plugin then open it back up. That is only good until I close it then it starts all over again. Is there anything I can do or is there something I am overlooking that is causing this to happen?

-Thanks

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have just discovered the same problem, leading me to your question! I'm going to take a wild guess and say it's a permissions issue but I can't see it yet.

Comment: Unfortunately no I haven't which is really unfortunate because this is such a great application and I love it but it lacks support. There are plugins I used which I need access to that I don't have right now. I have tried uninstalling the plugins and reinstalling and that doesn't fix anything.

Comment: I've contacted Panic support, I think this is a bug rather than anything we are doing.

Comment: Out of interest - are WVCPs and Emmet working? If you don't have those, would you mind installing them and letting me know if they stay in the plugins menu on quit? This way I can explain to Panic that we both have identical issues and that it's not to do with our systems.

Comment: No those aren't working ether. The only plugins that stay for me is PHP & Web Tool Kit, Tabber, Disable white out. All my other plugins don't stay installed. It's gotten to the point where they won't even install at all anymore.

Comment: I have the same issue - even when freshly downloaded form their respective websites. It's a Sunday so I don't expect a reply from Panic until tomorrow. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: Thanks please do keep me posted as it sounds like we have the same problem and tried all the same things. They have a google group but for some reason it won't give me access.

Comment: I'm going to post the results as an answer so anyone else that finds this can resolve the issue too.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working with Panic support and we've discovered there's an issue with certain plugins. Most likely, it's only one that's problematic. For me, it was WVCPs plugin. Removing that from the plugin folder allows all other plugins to work fine.

I found it helpful looking at the Console app for messages from Coda and one by one dropped the plugins back into the plugins folder until I found the one that caused an error about incompatible architecture.

You can ignore the error about two plugins implementing the same class, that seems to be a mutual exclusion sort of warning but still allows the other plugins to work.

One other plugin had a different error but again, appears to work fine so probably it was just a warning.

This is probably your best solution until Panic push out an update, which I am assured is on the way.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the info. How do I access the Console App? It seems I have more than one that is causing problems. I loaded them one at a time and a few up them wouldn't load. I would load one at a time then close it and re-open it. Load another one and repeat. I can't really pinpoint which one is causing it since the ones the load aren't there once I close it and re-open it.

Comment: Console is an application in your Applications/Utilities folder. You can type "coda" in the search box top right to filter messages for coda. Yeah it's unfortunately quite trial and error at this point!